# Slow server caused by mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb, cpu-usage, high-availability

I see the MongoDB usage extremely high. It shows it is using 756% of the cpu and the load is at 4

```
22527 root 20 0 0.232t 0.024t 0.023t S 756.2 19.5 240695:16 mongod
```

I checked the MongoDB logs and found that every question is taking more than 200ms to execute which is causing the high resource usage and speed issue .

Comment: Maybe you should make your text flash in bright orange as well.

Comment: Hi Ashish Swami, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your question is a little difficult to understand; are you worried that the cpu usage is making your MongoDB slow to process the queries, or is it the other way around: slow queries are making MongoDB very resource-hungry, and slowing everything else down?